# Find (Third) Email Found in Email Body and Send Email - Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a very nuanced problem that I have been spending 9 hours straight trying to figure out on Power Automate. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

1. When a New Email Arrives
2. Make the email body Compose
3. Use a Plumsail Connector to validate email addresses through Regex.
4. For each validation match create a Compose thaat holds Match O.
   If the Outputs of this compose is equal to "emailA@example.com" or "emailb@example.com" then do nothing.

I'm having an issue where I want the remaining outputs to be sent via email but the dynamic options don't have any outputs for the remaining options and I don't know what function I should use to do this.

I would settle for either if those EmailA or EmailB is true then make a new composed email with the validated email left.

I also had the issue where it validates the email and portions of the email so it tries to send multiple emails to different portions of the email as well so I get various failed attempt emails from Microsoft.

Lastly, I tried to attempt a "Do Until" loop that matched the output with the output in hopes that when the first output was found it would end the loop since the terminate option wouldn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can refer to this document to send an email: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/email-top-scenarios.

Comment: This page is great but it doesn't help in the scenario above. I want to find a connector or a function in power automate that will extract the third email found within an email body without it validating portions of that email address to send emails to additionally. Right now I am using a plumsail connector that gives me the outputs of every email validated in the email body and even splits certain validated emails into more invalid emails and sends them which causes a myriad of undeliverable messages to be sent to my inbox